# Using JS onclick function, the result displays and immediately disappears after each button click.

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, webforms, buttonclick

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: uri + '?' + 'sfield=' + $('#DropDownList1').val() + '&' + 'svalue=' + $('#TextBox1').val(),
        success: function (data) {
        searchData(data);
        }
    })
});

function searchData(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
        $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#splayers'));
    })
};
```

This is the JS functions I wrote. I also wrote a method GetPlayerInfo(string sfield, string svalue) so that I can invoke it in JS. However, every time when I click the Button1, the results displays like 0.1 seconds and then immediately disappers. I've tried Ajax, but same problem still exists except the page stops refreshing anymore.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the type of `Button1` `type="button"` or `type="submit"` or you didn't given a type?

Comment: How does `GetPlayerInfo()` factor in here? If `#Button1` is a submit button inside a form element (noting that `<button>` elements are submit buttons unless specified otherwise) that could explain the behaviour, as hinted at by the previous comment.

Comment: Can you show your html code as well ?